# Use aliases as custom commands in terminator

Tags: alias, command, gnome-terminator

I am using a terminator layout to start multiple terminals, and would like to call an alias at each terminal start which is defined in my `.bash_aliases` (called by both `.bashrc` and `.profile`). Terminator unfortunately doesn't know about those aliases when starting the terminals. How can I fix that?

I start terminator with this command:

```
terminator -l my_layout -f
```

EDIT:

As a temporary solution, I `ssh -A -YC` into myself and then run the alias. All this as a custom command.

Answer (score 0):

Set an environment variable for your Terminator windows, and call the aliases from your `.bashrc`. In terminator's config:

```
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child0]]]
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      type = Window
    [[[child1]]]
      labels = Alias0, Alias1, None
      order = 0
      parent = child0
      type = Notebook
    [[[terminal1]]]
      order = 0
      parent = alias0
      profile = root
      type = Terminal
    [[[terminal2]]]
      order = 1
      parent = child1
      profile = alias1
      type = Terminal
    [[[terminal3]]]
      order = 2
      parent = child1
      profile = default
      type = Terminal


[profiles]
  [[alias0]]
    custom_command = MY_ALIAS=0 bash
    use_custom_command = True
  [[alias1]]
    custom_command = MY_ALIAS=1 bash
    use_custom_command = True
```

And in `.bashrc`:

```
case $MYALIAS in
    0) alias0
        ;;
    1) alias1
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```